# Check if attribute is unique across two columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

My `Classroom` model has two attributes, a `student_classcode` and a `teacher_classcode`. I have an `after_create` callback to generate these two codes after the classroom is created. Currently, I only generate the student_classcode so far with this:

(taken from [here](http://daniel.fone.net.nz/blog/2014/12/10/handling-token-generation-collisions-in-activerecord/))

```
class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :generate_token

  private

    MAX_RETRIES = 10
    def generate_token
      update_column :student_classcode, SecureRandom.hex(4)
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => e
      @token_attempts = @token_attempts.to_i + 1
      retry if @token_attempts < MAX_RETRIES
      raise e, "Retries exhausted"
    end

end
```

Right now it makes sure that the `student_classcode` is unique (with up to 10 retries). I want to be able to generate a `teacher_classcode` as well, and I want to make sure that it is unique among the `teacher_classcode` column *and* the `student_classcode` column.

So for example, if Classroom A has the `student_classcode` '12345', and (by chance) the `teacher_classcode` of Classroom B generates to '12345', I want Classroom B to regenerate the classcode. Or, if Classroom B has the `student_classcode` 'abcde', and Classroom B has the `teacher_classcode` 'abcde', then I want Classroom B to regenerate the `teacher_classcode`.

I know that the chances of there being two of the same classcode across both columns are small, but I don't want to take the chances. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you make `Classcode` a model in its own right, with validations to ensure the code is unique. Then generate a generic code and through standard `belongs_to` associations from the `Classroom` you can associate a teacher and a student classcode.

This way you can be sure each classcode is unique and only have one implementation of code generation.

Comment: Good idea! Didn't think of that. Thanks.